# JupyterHub: shared folder permission for users

Tags: python, docker, jupyterhub

I am working on a containerized JupyterHub based on https://opendreamkit.org/2018/10/17/jupyterhub-docker project.
I have put it in a EC2 and all work fine: all my users have a private storage and shared storage to share its notebook.

Now i need to add new users and they need to see only a little part of the shared space. Then, I would like this configuration:

```
/shared/new_space/  >>> New users & Old users
/shared/            >>> Only old users
```

I am thinking to "play" with the the *DockerSpawner* but i don't have any idea how to do this.
I can put a new directory into the

```
c.DockerSpawner.volumes = {
    'jupyterhub-user-{username}': notebook_dir,
    '/home/ubuntu/efs-disk/data-shared': '/home/jovyan/shared'
    '/home/ubuntu/efs-disk/data-shared/NEW_SPACE': '/home/jovyan/shared/NEW_SPACE' #Need to try
}
```

but how can i do the users's permissions? Which component manages user permissions? Do you have any suggestion for completing my task?

Thanks in advance, regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a big search in the Web i find a solution [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner/issues/172):
Then i modify my jupyterhub_config.py as:

```
import os
from dockerspawner import DockerSpawner

class MyDockerSpawner(DockerSpawner):
    # Questa è la lista di Utenti che non vedranno la cartella sharedm ma solo la shared_notebooks
    denied_team = ['test1','test2','test3'] 
    def start(self):
        if self.user.name in self.denied_team:
            self.volumes['jupyterhub-user-{username}'] = {'bind': '/home/jovyan' , 'mode': 'rw'}
            self.volumes['/home/ubuntu/efs-disk/shared_notebooks'] = {'bind': '/home/jovyan/shared_notebooks', 'mode': 'rw'}
        else:
            self.volumes['jupyterhub-user-{username}'] = {'bind': '/home/jovyan' , 'mode': 'rw'}
            self.volumes['/home/ubuntu/efs-disk/data_shared'] = {'bind': '/home/jovyan/shared', 'mode': 'rw'}
            self.volumes['/home/ubuntu/efs-disk/shared_notebooks'] = {'bind': '/home/jovyan/shared_notebooks', 'mode': 'rw'}
        return super().start()


c.JupyterHub.spawner_class = MyDockerSpawner
c.JupyterHub.<OTHER-SETTINGS>
```

I would like to put the "denied_team" in a better position but for now I will not move it.

Regards